# asp.net mysql sql server 2008 installation

Tags: asp.net, mysql, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

i have a simple questions. I am programming in Visual studio using vb.net. As Database i am using mysql with the .Net connector and using the membership provider.

Do i need to install microsoft sql server 200X too ? (although i will not use it)

sincerly

Tasci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need it. These are different programs. They do not require each other for work.